# How to hide photos in Finder

Tags: mac, finder

I am using the most current version of my Mac (OS X El Capitan). While I am not at all tech savvy, I have been saving some photos I would rather not everyone allowed to see in folders under my Finder. I have not locked the folder yet, but I notice all my photos that I am hiding under photos show up under "All My Files", I am wondering if there is a way to have these photos NOT show up under All My Files and only be saved in those folders.

Thank You

Comment: If you know how to use the Terminal.app you could make all the photos _hidden files_ by adding a `.` to the start of each file name. Or, you could remove _All My Files_ from your Finder's sidebar and hope no one goes looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is not to allow other people to access your user account. If other people, (work colleagues, family members, friends, etc,) need to use your computer, create separate user accounts for them, or utilize the Guest account. If you have enabled `System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options > Automatic login` to login to your user account on startup, disable it now and use your Username or User icon and your password to login. Giving access to your user account to anybody who uses your computer is not a "best practice" and leaves your computer open to malicious or unintentional damage, as well as diminishing your privacy.